# Using Len Of A List To Create Django HTML Pages?

Tags: django

I know this has had to have been asked before, I can't seem to figure out the correct terminology to search to find what this is called or how to do it. I have a dynamic table that one day may have 5 items and the next 10 items (pulled from a DB), I am going to create hyperlinks within the table that would then open another HTML page specifically about that list object. I can't seem to figure out how to make this work? The way my mind works with Django right now is that I create a HTML file and URL view for each specific page, but if I one day want to create 3 and the next day 5 how can I do that, right now my mind can't understand how to dynamically create that HTML file for each thing in the list by using only one template? Just looking for someone to tell me what this is called if anything or what I can search in Django documentation to find examples? Edit after initial answer

Here is my app URL file:

URL

```
urlpatterns = [

    # The home page
    #path('', views.index, name='home'),


    # Matches any html file

    #path('charttest/', views.charttest, name='charts'),
    path('', views.nba, name='nba'),
    path('nbav2/', views.nba2, name='nba2'),
    path('nbav3/', views.nba3, name='nba3'),
    path('ncaa/', views.ncaa, name='ncaa'),
    path('nhl/', views.nhl, name='nhl'),
    path('testing/', views.current_game_table, name='testing'),
    path('your_details_view/<str:pk>', views.your_details_view, name='your_details_view')
}
```

Here is my views file:

```
def current_game_table(request):
    items = Nbav8.objects.using('totals').all()


    # rest of your code
    return render(request, 'home/testing.html', {'items': items})

def your_details_view(request, pk):

    item = Nbav8.objects.using('totals').get(pk=pk)

    current_day_home_team = list(Nbav8.objects.using('totals').values_list('home_team_field', flat=True))
    current_day_away_team = list(Nbav8.objects.using('totals').values_list('away_team_field', flat=True))

    awayuyu = []
    homeuyu = []

    for team in current_day_home_team:
        home_team_list1 = PreviousLossesNbav1WithDateAgg.objects.using('totals').filter(Q(away_team_field=team) | Q(home_team_field=team)).values_list('actual_over_under_result_field', flat=True)

        homeuyu.append(list(home_team_list1[:5]))


    home_team_list2 = homeuyu


    for team in current_day_away_team:
        away_team_list1 = PreviousLossesNbav1WithDateAgg.objects.using('totals').filter(Q(away_team_field=team) | Q(home_team_field=team)).values_list('actual_over_under_result_field', flat=True)
        away_teamdd = away_team_list1[:5]

        awayuyu.append(list(away_team_list1[:5]))


    away_team_list2 = awayuyu


    return render(request, 'home/testing2.html', {'item': item, 'away': away_team_list2, 'home': home_team_list2})
```

Here is the root URL file:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
"""

"""

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include  # add this


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),        
    path("", include("apps.authentication.urls")),
    path("", include("apps.home.urls")), 
]
```

Here is my testing.html

```
Hello World

{{ items }}

{% for item in items %}
        <a href="{% url for 'your_details_view' item.pk %}">{{ item }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Everytime I try to navigate to my webpage /testing I receive an error "Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name."

Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: https://www.total-scores.com/testing/

Django Version: 3.2.6
Python Version: 3.9.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'apps.home']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /home/jbarth200/priv-django-dashboard-gradient-pro-master/apps/templates/home/testing.html, error at line 6
   Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
   1 : Hello World
   2 : 
   3 : {{ items }}
   4 : 
   5 : {% for item in items %}
   6 :         <a href=" {% url for 'your_details_view' item.pk %} ">{{ item }}</a>
   7 : {% endfor %}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jbarth200/priv-django-dashboard-gradient-pro-master/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/jbarth200/priv-django-dashboard-gradient-pro-master/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/jbarth200/priv-django-dashboard-gradient-pro-master/./apps/home/views.py", line 1739, in current_game_table
    return render(request, 'home/testing.html', {'items': items})
  File "/home/jbarth200/priv-django-dashboard-gradient-pro-master/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/home/jbarth200/priv-django-dashboard-gradient-pro-master/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/home/jbarth200/priv-django-dashboard-gradient-pro-master/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/jbarth200/priv-django-dashboard-gradient-pro-master/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/jbarth200/priv-django-dashboard-gradient-pro-master/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/jbarth200/priv-django-dashboard-gradient-pro-master/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/jbarth200/priv-django-dashboard-gradient-pro-master/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/jbarth200/priv-django-dashboard-gradient-pro-master/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 211, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/home/jbarth200/priv-django-dashboard-gradient-pro-master/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/jbarth200/priv-django-dashboard-gradient-pro-master/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 446, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "/home/jbarth200/priv-django-dashboard-gradient-pro-master/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 86, in reverse
    return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jbarth200/priv-django-dashboard-gradient-pro-master/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 694, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /testing/
Exception Value: Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Models File:

```
class Nbav8(models.Model):
    home_team_field = models.TextField(db_column='HOME TEAM:', blank=True, null=True, primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_team_field = models.TextField(db_column='AWAY TEAM:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    projected_points_field = models.FloatField(db_column='PROJECTED POINTS:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_injury = models.TextField(db_column='Home Injury', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    away_injury = models.TextField(db_column='Away Injury', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    game_points_with_formula_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='GAME POINTS WITH FORMULA:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    game_money_line_field = models.FloatField(db_column='GAME MONEY LINE:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    over_or_under = models.TextField(db_column='OVER OR UNDER', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'nbav8'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you want is called a **detail** page.  I'm going to call the model Item.  You can create detail views for each item easily by doing something like the following on your urls.py:

```py
    # urls.py
    urlpatterns = [
        ...
        path('your_details_view/<int:pk>', views.your_details_view, name='your_details_view'),
        # or if your primary key is NOT an integer:
        path('your_details_view/<str:pk>', views.your_details_view, name='your_details_view'),
        ...
        ]
```

Your root urls.py looks different than I'm used to.  Perhaps is is correct, but give this a try.  Remove the `app` part, so like this:

```py
    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),        
        path("", include("authentication.urls")),
        path("", include("home.urls")), 
    ]
```

Then the following in your views:

```py
    # views.py

    # view of the page with all the links:
    def your_dynamic_table_view(request):
        items = Item.objects.all()
        # rest of your code
        return render(request, 'your_app/dynamic_table.html', {'items': items})

    # view for the details page
    def your_details_view(request, pk):
        # your code
        # Here is where you will get the particular item based 
        # on the pk that was in the <a href> link
        item = Item.objects.get(pk=pk)
        return render(request, 'your_app/detail_view.html', {'item': item})
```

Now, in your table you can put links to all items simply by iterating through them; something like this in your dynamic_table.html:

dynamic_view.html:

```html
    {% for item in items %}
        <a href="{% url 'your_details_view' item.pk %}">{{ item }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
```

Now the link will go to `your_details_view`, which will render an html page specific to the pk of that item.  (It doesn't have to be a pk, or even an integer). The `item.pk` in the href anchor tag is so that when you click on it it will go to the `your_details_view`, which will render an html page, `.../your_details_view/45` as an example, where 45 is the pk I made up for the particular item.  That `pk` variable (the primary key of the particular item) can then be used in your detail_view.html page, along with any of the item's fields:

detail_view.html:

```html
    Here you have access to the all of the fields
    of the particular item, say item with pk=45, if
    that is pk in the <a href> tag.  For example if the
    item has a field called price, then you can do:
    <p>The price of this item is: {{ item.price }}</p>
```

**Note** I just made up the name item.  For example, if you have a model you call `Item`, then in the template where you will have all the links (NOT the detail page), you can pass all the Item objects, and then iterate through them to create all the links.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241267/discussion-on-answer-by-r-uziel-using-len-of-a-list-to-create-django-html-pages).

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're getting the below values all the same is because you're sending the same list each time.  Notice that you are NOT sending the same item, since you are using the pk to get the specific item.  That's why each link on the top gets you something specific.

```py
def your_details_view(request, pk):

    # Here you are getting the SPECIFIC Nbav8 instance, and the links in your template,
    # <a href="{% url 'your_details_view' item.pk %}">{{ item }}</a>
    # the link will have that specific item's pk in the url, thus generating
    # a specific page to that item.
    item = Nbav8.objects.using('totals').get(pk=pk)

    # Everything beyond here looks like it's getting lists that do not depend 
    # on the specific item previously gotten.  
    current_day_home_team = list(Nbav8.objects.using('totals').values_list('home_team_field', flat=True))
    current_day_away_team = list(Nbav8.objects.using('totals').values_list('away_team_field', flat=True))

    awayuyu = []
    homeuyu = []

    for team in current_day_home_team:
        home_team_list1 = PreviousLossesNbav1WithDateAgg.objects.using('totals').filter(Q(away_team_field=team) | Q(home_team_field=team)).values_list('actual_over_under_result_field', flat=True)

        homeuyu.append(list(home_team_list1[:5]))


    home_team_list2 = homeuyu


    for team in current_day_away_team:
        away_team_list1 = PreviousLossesNbav1WithDateAgg.objects.using('totals').filter(Q(away_team_field=team) | Q(home_team_field=team)).values_list('actual_over_under_result_field', flat=True)
        away_teamdd = away_team_list1[:5]

        awayuyu.append(list(away_team_list1[:5]))


    away_team_list2 = awayuyu


    return render(request, 'home/testing2.html', {'item': item, 'away': away_team_list2, 'home': home_team_list2})
```

I'm not sure what specific list each Nbav8 object is supposed to get on it's page, and my lack of sports knowledge makes it harder to grasp what you're trying to show.

**Suggestions:**

Before going much further, there are some things you might want to address now, like

Not knowing your initial code, I made up a name `your_details_view`, but a more natural name might be `current_game` so that it matches up with your table of many `current_game`'s.

Having names with spaces in the url is not such a great idea.  Maybe you can add a field to your Nbav8 objects like url_name, and use that instead of pk in the anchor tag and path.

```py
path('your_details_view/<str:url_name>', views.your_details_view, name='your_details_view'),
```

Then in your html

```html
<a href="{% url 'your_details_view' item.url_name %}">{{ item }}</a>
```

**Bottom Line**

You have to figure out a way in you `your_details_view` to create a list that is specific to the item, so that when you send it to that item's detail page, only that list will appear.