# Using Primary Key To Index HTML Template Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

Bit confused on how I would index a list I have based on the primary key in the HTML template?
Here is my views page:

```
def current_game_table(request):
    items = list(Nbav8.objects.using('totals').all())
    return render(request, 'home/testing.html', {'items': items})

def current_games(request, pk):

    item = Nbav8.objects.using('totals').get(pk=pk)
    items2 = list(CurrentDayStats.objects.using('totals').values_list('home_team_over_under_field', flat=True))
    return render(request, 'home/testing2.html', {'item': item, 'uuup':items2})
```

Here is my testing1.html:

```
Hello World

{{ items }}

{% for item in items %}
        <a href="{% url 'current_games' item.pk %}">{{ item.home_team_field }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is my testing2.html:

```
<p>The price of this item is: {{ item }}</p>


Where is it?!!?

{{ item.uuup }}
```

URL file:

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from apps.home import views

urlpatterns = [



    # The home page
    #path('', views.index, name='home'),


    # Matches any html file

    #path('charttest/', views.charttest, name='charts'),
    path('', views.nba, name='nba'),
    path('nbav2/', views.nba2, name='nba2'),
    path('nbav3/', views.nba3, name='nba3'),
    path('ncaa/', views.ncaa, name='ncaa'),
    path('nhl/', views.nhl, name='nhl'),
    path('testing/', views.current_game_table, name='testing'),
    path('current_games/<int:pk>', views.current_games, name='current_games')
```

My pages display fine testing1 shows my pages as I want for testing purposes, my problem is this. On my testing2.html page that displays, I have a list "uuup", my problem is, I only want to show uuup.0 on page 1, uuup.1 on page 2, uuup.2 on page 3, etc. I can't seem to figure out how to use the pk as an index? I set a diff variable in my views page and set it to int(item) and printed it out on each page to confirm that each subpage showed it as 1/2/3/4/etc so I am unsure how to call it to use an index to my "uuup" list?

After the update you gave here is the error I am getting:

```
Reverse for 'current_games' with arguments '(1, 0)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['current_games/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']
1   Hello World
2   
3   {{ items }}
4   
5   {% for item in items %}
6       <a href="{% url 'current_games' item.pk forloop.counter0 %}">{{ item.home_team_field }}</a>
7   {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can slice in your view like this:

```
def current_games(request, pk):
     item = Nbav8.objects.using('totals').get(pk=pk)
     index = pk - 1
     items2 = CurrentDayStats.objects.using('totals').values_list('home_team_over_under_field', flat=True)[index]
     return render(request, 'home/testing2.html', {'item': item, 'uuup':items2})
```

Using pk as index is not right the reason being pk value is not consistent instead you can do something like this:

testing1.html:

```
{% for item in items %}
    <a href="{% url 'current_games' item.pk forloop.counter0 %}">{{ item.home_team_field }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

urls.py:

```
path('current_games/<int:pk>/<int:page>/', views.current_games, name='current_games')
```

views.py:

```
def current_games(request, pk, page):
     item = Nbav8.objects.using('totals').get(pk=pk)
     items2 = CurrentDayStats.objects.using('totals').values_list('home_team_over_under_field', flat=True)[page]
     return render(request, 'home/testing2.html', {'item': item, 'uuup':items2})
```

Comment: So that displays each item in my table, my problem is, I'm only trying to display uuup[0] on page /current_games/1 and the on /current_games/2 I want to display uuup[1]. I added my URL file in the event that helps at all

Comment: But using pk as index doesn't seem right.

Comment: That could very well be true, here is the original question to how I got here haha. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70763271/using-len-of-a-list-to-create-django-html-pages. I find myself having a hard time grasping the whole dynamically creating a html page, and furthermore how I can display only one row or even better one cell of my sql table on each page created as I don't create a table for each game, I create a table for all games and then try to parse that data from the table into each view. I'm not very good at explaining it either.

Comment: Check my updated answer

Comment: Thanks for the help making this correct, but now I do get an error, posted in original question.

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: Reverse for 'current_games' with arguments '(1, 0)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['current_games/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']
1   Hello World
2   
3   {{ items }}
4   
5   {% for item in items %}
6       <a href="{% url 'current_games' item.pk forloop.counter0 %}">{{ item.home_team_field }}</a>
7   {% endfor %}

Comment: Define duplicate url without last parameter like this: `path('current_games/<int:pk>', views.current_games, name='current_games')`

Comment: So in my URL page I do not add it like you have it? or I add another path into my URL file like you posted and not change the existing one?

Comment: Yes add another that i included in my answer and keep existing there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works. I guess not using pk makes sense, but I don't get the page call? Is that a django built in function? I am also a little confused on how you call the same view into a different URL?