# Django not bringing pk to template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am at the moment practicing my Django-Skills and I am learning a language, so I thought I could combine these two learning paths:

I have a models.py

```
class Word(models.Model):
    English = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    German = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Bahasa_Indonesia = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

and a class based view, which returns the word-list with a specified language:

```
class WordListByLanguageView(View):
    '''outputs all the words in a selected language as a list.
    The link to the detail forwards to word-detail.
    '''
    def get(self, request, language):
        words = Word.objects.all().values(language)  # retrieves only the language field
        return render(request, 'word_list.html', {'words': words, 'language': language})
```

I want users to pick which language they want to learn on their dashboard:

```
{% block content %}
<h1>User Dashboard</h1>
<form method="post" action="{% url 'user-dashboard' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <label for="language">Start learning </label>
  <select name="language" id="language">
    <option value="English">English</option>
    <option value="German">German</option>
    <option value="Bahasa_Indonesia">Bahasa Indonesia</option>
    <!-- Add more language options as needed -->
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Start Learning</button>
</form>


{% endblock %}
```

```
class UserDashboardView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        # Render the user dashboard template
        return render(request, 'user_dashboard.html')

    def post(self, request):
        # Get the selected language from the form submission
        language = request.POST.get('language')

        # Redirect to the word list URL with the selected language as a parameter
        return redirect('word-list-language', language=language)
```

The path is: Users pick an option on the dashboard (English, German, Bahasa Indonesia) and are then redirected to a list where they can pick a word which should then forward them to a detail-view where they have to enter the word in the language they choose to practice.

My word-list looks like this:

```
<h1> Hi from the word list</h1>

    <ul>
        {% for word in words %}
            <li><a href="{{ word.language }}">{{ word|get_item:language }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endblock %}
```

the output I need is for the href-attribute:
`href="{{picked _language}}/{{word.pk}}"`

So I started fooling around and asking chat-gpt what's going on. The AI is clueless. As am I.

I also have an attr.py in templatetags with the following content:

```
@register.filter
def attr(obj, attr):
    return getattr(obj, attr)

@register.filter
def get_item(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary.get(key)
```

edit:

```
<h1> Hi from the word list</h1>

    <ul>
        {% for word in words %}
            <li><a href="{{ language }}/{{ word.id }}">{{ word|get_item:language }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    <ul>
        {% for word in words %}
            <li>{{ word.English }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

the latter part (outputting the English words) works :-D

Can somebody help with this? :-D
I am at a loss :-(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Primary Key To Index HTML Template Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70858656/using-primary-key-to-index-html-template-django)

Comment: not really :-D 

I might have a problem with the model. 
Curerntly I am thinking that I might be better of having two models: 
One for the "base-word" and one for the translations ... but not sure ...

Comment: i've given it an honest try and i still barely understand what you're asking. It's not entirely clear what the thing is you have tried and what error message you're getting. My first thought was that django refuses to resolve`pk` in templates, but i spun up a local django for testing and it works fine.

Comment: The template word_list.html is supposed to list all words according to a selected language.
at the moment, I wanted to go back to the WORD-model (yes, I should have branched - it's half a day of work, no I didn't ) I need to figure out my DB first and then I'll be back here :-D 

I thought I expressed myself clearly... obviously I didn't ... :-(

Comment: In case you want to give it a try: 
https://github.com/WunschK/VocabularyTrainer

Comment: it's 404, probably private repo

Comment: whoops :-D to stressed RN ... should work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254131/discussion-between-sebastian-wozny-and-kwunsch).